# UITableView appears bigger than set

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have build a simple UIViewController in my storyboard with a navigation bar on top, a UITableView and a UITextView on the bottom.

When I am starting the app a animation is fired and the height of the TableView will be reduced about the same value like the height of the TextView on the bottom will increased. This works very well when I am watching my NSLogs which show the changes. But if I have a look at the same time on my GUI the TextView is increased but the TableView is not changing in any way. Also if I want to scroll down to see all my TableViewCells I can notice that there was no change due to the fact that the TableView scrolls back after I release my finger.

Here is my code:
(the "frame" is the frame of the TextView "_tLive")

```
- (void)MySetTextViewWithFrame: (CGRect)frame
{
    if ([self.view.subviews containsObject: _tLive])
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^
        {
            _tLive.frame = frame;
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        _tLive = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
        _tLive.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _tLive.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        _tLive.delegate = (id)self;
        _tLive.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        _tLive.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(MyStartLiveChat)];
        [_tLive addGestureRecognizer: tap];
        [self.view addSubview: _tLive];
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^
    {
        CGRect newTableViewFrame = CGRectMake(_tvCommands.frame.origin.x, _tvCommands.frame.origin.y, _tvCommands.frame.size.width, frame.origin.y - _tvCommands.frame.origin.y);

        NSLog(@"View Frame: x:%0.0f, y:%0.0f, width:%0.0f, height:%0.0f", frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
        NSLog(@"End of TableView: %0.0f", newTableViewFrame.size.height + newTableViewFrame.origin.y);
        NSLog(@"Beginning of _tLive: %0.0f", frame.origin.y);
        _tvCommands.frame = newTableViewFrame;

        NSLog(@"Final TableView Frame: x:%0.0f, y:%0.0f, width:%0.0f, height:%0.0f", _tvCommands.frame.origin.x, _tvCommands.frame.origin.y, _tvCommands.frame.size.width, _tvCommands.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

Here are my logs:

```
2014-08-10 17:20:31.922 App [542:60b] View Frame: x:0, y:533, width:320, height:35 
2014-08-10 17:20:31.923 App [542:60b] End of TableView: 533 
2014-08-10 17:20:31.925 App [542:60b] Beginning of _tLive: 533 
2014-08-10 17:20:31.928 App [542:60b] Final TableView Frame: x:0, y:68, width:320, height:465
```

...

```
2014-08-10 17:21:02.490 App [550:60b] View Frame: x:0, y:344, width:320, height:224
2014-08-10 17:21:02.491 App [550:60b] End of TableView: 344
2014-08-10 17:21:02.492 App [550:60b] Beginning of _tLive: 344
2014-08-10 17:21:02.493 App [550:60b] Final TableView Frame: x:0, y:68, width:320, height:276
```

I've also tried to set the contentSize of the TableView but without success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used autolayout in your storyboard, the above code won't work. Try disabling autolayout in your storyboard.

Comment: wow! thank you very much! it works perfectly! I have no idea what auto layout exactly does but I will figure it out to understand the concept. GREAT!